# Почему не корректно работают вебсокеты на машине оракл(4 ядра, 24 гб)?

Tags: websocket, vps, vds

На локальной машине все работает хорошо, на replit ide(replit.com) все тоже норм, но вот на дедике от оракл(4 ядра, 24 гб оза) после 1 мин или раньше ответ от сервера приходит с опозданием, тобиш как на скрине сначала ~ 0.11 сек задержки(норм все), а затем увеличивается задержка(таймстеп)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и вылетает ошибка: "Error ping load: sent 1011 (unexpected error) keepalive ping timeout; no close frame received"[image: ошибка]

формула задержки = таймстеп(сервера) - локальний таймстеп
часть кода:

```
async with websockets.connect(url) as ws:
            sub_param = {"op": "subscribe", "args": channels}
            await ws.send(json.dumps(sub_param))

            while True:
                try:
                    res = await asyncio.wait_for(ws.recv(), timeout=25)
                except (asyncio.TimeoutError, websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed) as e:
                    try:
                        await ws.send('ping')
                        print("Error Res: ", await ws.recv())
                        continue
                    except Exception as e:
                        print("Error ping load:", e)
                        break
                       
                res = json.loads(res)
                print(res["data"])
```

Comment: Очень интересное наблюдение! А при запуске локально - одни нули будут в значениях задержки? И еще - может, есть какой то простой способ запустить это и у меня на машинке в oracl cloud и тоже посмотреть, возникает же такая задержка или нет?

Comment: ну задержка высчитывается по формуле локал таймстеп(время сейчас) - таймстеп из ответа (сервера) т.е. примерно 0.11 сек. плюс минус. На оракле так же сначала, а потом делается большая задержк(десятки секунд) и ошибка. Тобиш локально приблезительно все время 0.11 сек ну иногда скачет на пару ответов но это такое